# replacing quotes with sed leads to ^@

Tags: linux, sed, special-characters, vi, double-quotes

I am trying to replace the double quotes around values in a file which looks like 
below

```
----"7001732469"|"LAWRENCE CITY CAREER TECH CTR"|
```

I tried using this `sed "s/\"//g"` and even deleting them from a file `tr -d '"'` - all these work fine, but the issue is when I open the re-directed(via vi) , it has no quotes(well and good) , but it has characters like `^@` and `^E`.

No matter what I do with Sed it just turns into this and I am now finding it hard to get rid of this.

Any idea on why it happens ans how to avoid it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

^@ is a null and ^E is a transmission control character.  Your sed command works just fine for me:

```
$ sed "s/\"//g" file1 > file2
```

Something else must be going on.  Is it possible these control characters exist in the original file?  Exactly WHERE are the control characters showing up (could be a clue)?

http://ascii-table.com/control-chars.php

Comment: I just found something strange - it looks like a problem with my vi(which I am not sure why and how) when my cat or head or tail my new file it just stays fine as I expect, but only when I vi it throws up everywhere, I just can't see pattern its everywhere.

Comment: I just thought of something.  We received a file from one of our vendors once that was sent incorrectly in unicode (16-bit characters).  Some programs interpreted and displayed the characters just fine, some didn't, showing ^@ in front of every character (the NULL portion of the character that was not used).  Perhaps you have a character set mismatch here?